# Pull all rows with policy number X where at least one row has trans code of Y using TSQL

Tags: t-sql, where-clause, temp-tables

I have a table with rows `policy_nbr` and `trans_cd`. There are multiple trans_cd's per policy (even of the same type). I would like to pull all policy records where said policy has a `trans_cd` of 'ER' or 'RO'.  So any `policy_nbr` that has a `trans_cd` of 'ER' or 'RO' associated with it I want to pull all of the entries with that `policy_nbr` into some new temp table, not just the ones with 'ER' or 'RO'.

The code I have right now is this:

```
SELECT * FROM urs_prem_detail_interim
INTO ER_RO_urs_prem_detail
WHERE uws_trans_cd IN ('ER','RO')
```

But I know this won't really work. For instance, if I have `policy_nbr` '123' and there is an entry of this policy number with `trans_cd` of 'ER' then I want to pull all values with `policy_nbr` 123, not just the one with the 'ER' like my current code is doing.

Any help is much appreciated! I apologize if my explanation is confusing.

Comment: You can use sub-query or join it with the same table to get your desired result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sub-query: The inner `select` query will pull in all the policy_nbr for trans_cd as 'ER' or 'RO' and then the outer query will pull all the records with matching policy_nbr.

```
select *
  from urs_prem_detail_interim
 where policy_nbr in (select distinct policy_nbr
                        from urs_prem_detail_interim
                       where uws_trans_cd in ('ER', 'RO'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a *subselect*. I'm not familiar with TSQL much any more, but this would be the gist:

```
    SELECT * FROM urs_prem_detail_interim
    INTO ER_RO_urs_prem_detail
    WHERE policy_nbr in
      (SELECT policy_nbr FROM urs_prem_detail_interim
      WHERE uws_trans_cd IN ('ER','RO'))
```

This should work to insert records into an existing table `ER_RO_urs_prem_detail`. You may need to use a `CREATE TABLE ER_RO_Urs_prem_detail AS SELECT...` if you want to do it in one step.

Test your query without the `INTO..` phrase to ensure you're getting the right data.